# Figuring out N = 23 Birthday Problem - Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

I am incredibly frustrated so please excuse me.

I know I can just run the computations but I am struggling to figure out algebraically how I can figure out that n = 23 whereby it takes a minimum of 23 people required for the possibility of 2 people having a birthday on the same day within a year to roughly equal 1/2.

Could someone please help me with this.

I have used the standard notation below which will calculate the given probability of the event not occurring:

$$\frac {1}{2} = \frac{365!}{365^n(365-n)}$$

However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the reverse algebraically.

Additionally, I have looked at a number of other forums and I have not found one discussing this aspect.

Thanks

Comment: this is not clear.  Why should there be an exact value for $n$?  And, even if you'll take an approximate value, why should there be a simple closed formula for it?  Just do it numerically. Note:  did you mean to have $(365-n)!$ in the denominator?

Comment: @lulu Hey, lol. So it is one of those types of questions again. How large must    be so that the probability that at least two of them have the same birthday is at least 1/2?

Comment: Right.  Just do it numerically.  Compute your (corrected) expression for $n$ until you get values that work.

Comment: @lulu I just wanted to know if there was some way I could do this algebraically. Thanks though, thought I would just ask. I started to feel incredibly dumb.

Comment: Well, there isn't.  Nothing sensible anyway, nothing that won't entail numerical work of some sort.  Happily, the numerical work is easy in this case.

Comment: If you want to look at a case where even the numerical methods are rough, ask for the least number $N$ such that the probability that at least three people share a birthday is at least $\frac 12$.  There, it's tricky to write out the probability for any given $N$.

Comment: In probability, it is easy to fall into a trap of the kind "Bertrand paradox" (have you heard of it ?): you must first describe the **set of elementary events** on which you work with usual notations for sets (is it a product of sets, a union, etc. ?). Otherwise, probability is full of problems like yours.

Comment: As @lulu says, you should have been trying to find the smallest $n$ such that $\frac {1}{2} \le  \frac{365!}{365^n(365-n)!}$ with a factorial in the denominator.  If you make [Wikipedia's suggested approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximation_of_number_of_people) of $\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14-2d\log_e(1-p)}$ with $p=\frac12$ and $d=365$ you get $n \approx 22.99994$ which looks better than it really is: the exact value for equality using gamma functions is closer to $n\approx 22.76769$.  Rounded, this approximation does not always give the exact integer, but is close

Comment: Not as good as henry's but what I convinced myself of in high school was for $\frac {365\cdot 364 \cdot ..... (365-n)}{365\cdot 365\cdot.....} <\approx \frac {avg(365,365-n)^n}{365^n}=(\frac {\frac {730-n}2}{365})^n=(1-\frac n{730})^n$ And just try those for values $n=10,20,30,25,23$.  Helps to have plenty of time, a high penchant for boredom and a brand-new latest of the market Texas Instrument Calculator that you are just dying to play with.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have never heard of it before. I only recently realised how much I loved maths. I used to be really good when I was younger but let my own personal stuff affect my concentration but I honestly find it to be such a peaceful and therapeutic thing now. I will look into that paradox.

Comment: @Henry That is exactly what I was looking for. Slight typo leaving out the factorial in the denominator. I knew it was not going to be exactly 23 but that is perfect. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @fleablood lol, that sounds good :D Definitely need to upgrade my calculator

Comment: " I will look into that paradox"  It's not a paradox (that irks most mathematicians).  It's just counter intuitive... and it's not really that counterintuitive if you've ever played with exponential or geometric growth.

Comment: @Henry You meant smallest $n$ such that $\frac {1}{2} \ge  \frac{365!}{365^n(365-n)!}$?

Comment: @fleablood I have never played with either as I have mentioned. Hence not all of this is intuitive just yet. I only learnt about Binomial CFD last night.

Comment: @Henry Any chance you know where these approximation formulas are derived from? As in how would I know to use this, baring learning it from that page? Even a name would be helpful, I will research it on my own.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Yes - thank you

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist [The argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#An_upper_bound_on_the_probability_and_a_lower_bound_on_the_number_of_people) goes that $1-p = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(1-\frac kd\right) \approx \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(e^{-k/d} \right) = e^{-n(n-1)/(2d)}$ so $n^2-n \approx -2d\log_e(1-p)$ which is a solvable quadratic.  It is not exact since $1-\frac kd\not = e^{-k/d}$

Comment: @Henry Wow, thanks. I have a lot to learn. I appreciate your time :)

Comment: @Henry I roughly understand everything. The only thing I am a little uncertain of(I do not have a lot of experience with exponential growth and inequalities so please forgive me) Why do they choose to make use of the inequality 1 − x < e^-x ?

Comment: $e^{-x} =1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots$ and here $x=\frac{k}{d}$ is fairly small so $x^2$ etc are even smaller

Comment: @Henry I see. Thank you for that clarity.

Comment: For general information:  as somebody who deals with this sort of thing all the time, closed formulas are so rare as to be irrelevant.  This is a numerical game.  I'm grateful when the numerical problem is clear cut.  Even that is very rare.

Comment: @lulu To clarify your statement. This would not be classified as closed due to it having the capacity to be an infinite set. Am I correct?(Will get to your level eventually)

Comment: @lulu Sorry, don't mean to spam. Stack Timeout Editing error. Also, do you have any recommendations as to how I would go about improving my Numerical Analysis? I genuinely tried creating my own formulas/solutions with this and tbh I actually got close to the below post (baring using e). So I just think my overall Math is weaker than it needs to be for the time being. Hence I feel I just need to expose myself to more concepts, proofs, etc.

Comment: No specific advice about numerical work... Just do a lot of examples. Try doing some of these problems by sampling, for instance.  Often, that's the best you can do

Comment: @lulu Awesome, will do. Thanks dude (Unisex). Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137917/discussion-on-question-by-notreallyolivertwist-figuring-out-n-23-birthday-prob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using probability approximations :

$P$(no collision among $n$ people) = (1 - $\frac{1}{365}) \times (1-\frac{2}{365})\times ...\times (1-\frac{n-1}{365}) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{i}{365})$

$1 - i < e^{-i}$ via Taylor series and if $\frac{i}{N} << 1$ (which is often the case in crypto) $e^{-\frac{i}{N}} \sim 1-\frac{i}{N}$.

So we can write :

$\prod_{i = 1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{i}{365}) \approx \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1}e^{-\frac{i}{365}} = e^{-\frac{1+2+...+n-1}{365}}=e^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2 \times 365}}$.

$P$(having at least one collision among $n$ people) $=1-e^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2 \times 365}}$

if we set the probability to be exactly $0.5$ :

$0.5 = 1-e^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2 \times 365}}$

$0.5 = e^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2 \times 365}}$

$ln(\frac{1}{2}) = -\frac{n(n-1)}{730}$

$n(n-1) = 730 \times ln(2)$

Now you have two ways :

1. Resolve it considering a polynomial in $n$
2. Use approximation for $n >> 1$ : $n^2 \approx n(n-1)$

Using 1 :

$n^2 - n - 730 \times ln(2) = 0$ gives two roots but we consider only the positive : $n_1 = 23$ with $\Delta = (-1)^2 - 4 \times 1 \times (-730) \times ln(2) \approx 2025$.

Finally we might say to have exactly 0.5 probalility of collision we need 23 people.

Notes :

- as stated @lulu you should try to find the minimal $n$ for a probability of at least $0.5$,
- this is an approximation, you should find a real close and inferior to 23,
- there are other methods, I recall doing it with Stirling years ago.

Comment: Have never heard of Stirling. I will take a look at that. Man, this is an awesome break down. I have so much to learn. Thank you for taking the time to write that up for me!